# How to make properly concurrent javascript asynchronous promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback

**strong text**

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('tick');
}, 2000);

async function sumIncrementally() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
      result += i;
    }
    resolve(result);
  });

  promise.then(console.log);
}

sumIncrementally();
```

Till Now, the output is like,

49999999990067860000
tick
tick
...

Here, I want to get output like

tick
tick
....
tick
49999999990067860000
tick
tick
...

How Can I get this like of concurrency in javascript?

Comment: You realise that javascript is [single threaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts#javascript_is_single-threaded) right? There are some things you can do but you need to understand the threading model.

Comment: See: [Can promises be used to handle really long and blocking loops in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262471)

Comment: Your `for` loop is synchronous, which means it will block the thread until it is done looping. So simply using `async` is not going to make it run concurrently with other code. If you have an _actual_ asynchronous operation, then it _will_ run concurrently with other asynchronous operations, but if actually want to run blocking code concurrently with other code, then you should consider using a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker)